# Can't view texture in Maya rigs

Tags: python, maya

I've downloaded 3 rigs from Agora for Maya, Alpha, Beta, & Delta. All 3 rigs share the same problem: their textures don't show up at all.

[Source of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sz4UK.png)

I keep getting this error and I don't know what do.

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gac6V.jpg)

I've run the python script that was provided with each rig and the same problem persists.

[Python Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x2Oi.jpg)
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gac6V.jpg)

I've asked the Agora Studio and I haven't received a response back after I provided specifications. I've went to the Agora Discord and I don't have permission to ask a question and have found no solution so far.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: In the animation/vfx field, you should avoid any path names with spaces and things like `Matthew's` that's never a good idea and often lead to problems. Try first with a clean path and see if it works better.

Comment: Just testet it and yes, the strange path is the problem.

Comment: @haggikrey How do I go about changing the path? I've tried to use the File Path editor in Maya and it apparently can't find it.

Comment: Sorry, I have no much experience with the filepath editor, if I have to change a lot of paths, I mostly do it with python.